# How to tell IE to ignore previously received malformed HTML and render different HTML?

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

We have an MVC.Net 2 application running with .Net 4.0.  There are cases where embedded code in our views may err, sending malformed HTML to the browser.

How can I tell Internet Explorer to close any open attributes and elements so it can properly render an error message?

To catch and log errors in the embedded code, I'm enclosing the view's HTML and embedded code in the try block of a try-catch structure and just want a simple message displayed to the user after logging the error.

Example:

```html
<%
try {
%>
<div id="div1">
    <label class="<%=embedded.code.that.may.err%>">mylabel</label>
    <div id="div2" class="data-style">
        <%=more.embedded.code.that.may.err%>
    </div>
</div>
<%
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    (new LogManager()).Save(ex);
%>
<div style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:large;">
    Sorry, there was an error.
</div>
<%
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't. Have your error prone code run and put the result into string variables. Put that in the try-catch block. Then, it there's no error you can write out the entire #div1 block including your already evaluated strings knowing that there won't be an error.

Comment: I was afraid I get an answer like this.

The example above is a vast simplification of the HTML, Client Script, and embedded server script I'm really dealing with.  So there will be a lot of refactoring to pull logic that may err into separate embedded code regions covered by a try-catch structure and then render plain text variables throughout the view.

However, I'll pass this suggestion to the team lead.

Comment: Decided to follow this route.  Lots of refactoring to move all logic that could possibly err and place it inside a `try` block to populate `string` (or `MvcHtmlString`) variables for later rendering.  I don't anticipate `<%=stringVar%>` or `<%=MvcHtmlStringVar%>` to err when rendering the page.