# Generic type constraint to prohibit certain types?

Tags: c#, generics

I'd like to create a generic method:

```cs
MvcHtmlString MyMethod<T>(this HtmlHelper html, string title, IEnumerable<T> value)
```

I have many variables in my code which are `List<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `xxxCollection`, `T[]`, etc...  This method also has an overload which will take non enumerable values.  Is it possible to prohibit specific classes (such as `string`) in the type parameter constraints?

I've already created one overload like this:

```cs
MvcHtmlString MyMethod<T>(this HtmlHelper html, string title, object value)
```

This overload is good for dealing with individual values, but dealing with collections of values requires a slightly different implementation.  However, `string` implements `IEnumerable` so all my string variables will be sent to the wrong overload unless I can tell the compiler that they should be excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not use constraints for this and you do not need them, considering your intention of dealing with `string`.

Given your existing method that accepts type `object`, an argument of type `string` would result in your proposed new overload, since `IEnumerable<char>` is a better match than `object`. However, you need not abandon your thought of having an overload, nor should you need to resort to runtime checking. Simply create an additional overload for `string`. Sidestep the whole decision between `object` and `IEnumerable<T>` by making the scenario even easier for the compiler.

Given

```
void Foo(object argument)
{
    Console.WriteLine("object");
}

void Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> argument)
{
    Console.WriteLine("enumerable T");
}

void Foo(string argument)
{
    Console.WriteLine("string");
}
```

An method invocation list of

```
Foo("hello");
Foo(1);
Foo(new int[] { 1 });
```

Produces the output

```
string
object
enumerable T
```

You could then further coerce your string into your object overload in a single place.

```
void Foo(string argument)
{
    // Console.WriteLine("string");
    Foo((object)argument);
}
```

Comment: Yes is the route I'm going.  It will be awhile before I can verify my results ( I'm refactoring the whole view, to remove error prone logic from being mixed with the HTML.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577463/how-to-tell-ie-to-ignore-previously-received-malformed-html-and-render-different )

Comment: +1. And if you want "exclude" (as discourage/prevent) you can mark `string` overload as obsolete.

Comment: I was just trying to get the compiler to use the `object` overload when it encountered a string rather than the `IEnumerable` overload, so I won't be marking anything as obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

No. [Generic type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) constraints can only enforce *positive* constraints not *negative* constraints.

Run-time type checking is probably the way to go:

```
MvcHtmlString MyMethod<T>(this HtmlHelper html, string title, IEnumerable<T> value)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
        throw new IllegalOperationException(...);
    }
}
```

If all the types you want to pass to your method inherit from the same base class, or implement the same interface, you can use **jrummell**'s suggestion of a single constraint to enforce inheritance.

Although it's much more inelegant, another way of doing this if you want to support heterogeneous types would be providing enough overloads to handle your particular use cases:

```
// supports int, float, DateTime, etc.
MvcHtmlString MyMethod(this HtmlHelper html, string title, IEnumerable<int> value)
MvcHtmlString MyMethod(this HtmlHelper html, string title, IEnumerable<float> value)
MvcHtmlString MyMethod(this HtmlHelper html, string title, IEnumerable<DateTime> value)

// supports implementations of MyInterface
MvcHtmlString MyMethod(this HtmlHelper html, string title, IEnumerable<IMyInterface> value)
```

In the above example you would not be able to call `MyMethod<string>` since it doesn't satisfy any of the provided type constraints. Note that you can't use type constraints for this though as they are not part of the method signature.

Comment: If you make `MyMethod` a non-generic method in a generic class `Foo<T>`, you can place the type check in a static constructor so the constraint only needs to be checked once per time the application is run instead of once per time `MyMethod` is called.

Comment: Make sure to use a very specific/detailed exception message, as tracking down exceptions thrown in a static constructor can be challenging otherwise.

Comment: My concern is that many times the value I would pass is would be a string and I want the string handled by the non-IEnumerable overload.  However, string implements `IEnumerable` thus it would be handled by the wrong overload and instead of getting results like `string value` I'd end up with `s, t, r, i, n, g,  , v, a, l, u, e`.  The second result is appropriate for lists of strings, but not for strings themselves.

Comment: @Zarepheth ahh I see. In that case, I would check that `typeof(T) == `typeof(char)` and if so pass the string to the appropriate method. You would probably want to have an internal method which won't confuse the compiler like `internal MyMethodSingle(...)`

Comment: +1. @Zarepheth, more specific (non-generic) overloads are taken first - so implement non-generic versions for types you want to exclude (or handle specifically). You can even mark one you don't want with "Obsolete" attribute to show warnings/errors.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only want to use this extension for Model types, you could create a Model base class and restrict `T` to types implementing it.

```
MvcHtmlString MyMethod<T>(this HtmlHelper html, string title, IEnumerable<T> value)
    where T : ModelBase
```

Comment: I plan to use it on each of a couple dozen properties from the Model.  Most properties are single values, usually `string`.  A few are collections, usually `List<string>` and some are of other types.  Since the intent of the method, as viewed from the view, is the same for each property, I was planning to use overloads to implement the slightly different rendering between individual values and collections of values.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

You can only specify the following types of constraints:

```
where T : struct               // T must be a value type
where T : class                // T must be a reference type
where T : new()                // T must have a parameterless constructor
where T : <base class name>    // T must inherit from <base class>
where T : <interface name>     // T must implement <interface>
where T : U                    // T must inherit from U, where U is another
                               // generic parameter
```

Reference: [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Now, you can use some of these to restrict, but not to lock types out, only to specify the types you allow, such as the interface implementation constraint.

You can use the interface or base class constraint to specifically say "the types I allow must all have the following characteristic". I would say this would be your best option.

Are you sure generics is the right tool here?

Comment: What I wanted was to overload the method so that lists are treated one way and individual values are treated in a slightly different manner.  The intent of my question was to get the compiler to place strings in the individual value overload and lists in the IEnumberable overload.

From my research and the responses thus far, I think I should skip the overloads and use different names for the two methods.