# Is it possible to exclude IEnumerable and primitive types from Object parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

I have this extension method:

```
public static T Foo<T>(this Object current) where T : class, new()
{
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to exclude primitive types and IEnumerable interface from "this Object current"?

**Editet**
My question is not a duplicate, because in suggested question problem is in collision of parameters between overload methods. Author asked, is it possible to exclude String type from one of methods to give abbility for another method to pick it. And helpful answer for that question is not helpful for me

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic type constraint to prohibit certain types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621454/generic-type-constraint-to-prohibit-certain-types)

Comment: And what this method does so that it's invalid only for primitives and IEnumerable? Maybe it's possible to narrow down list of _allowed_ types.

Comment: @Evk as I understand, it should be any class with fields/properties or anonymous object

Comment: And still, what this method does? What's the output? Most primitives are structs so they are already excluded by "class" constaint. That leaves us with strings and IEnumerables, is there no way to do something sensible with them? For example - return string as is.

Comment: @Evk this method is custom mapper. T is outgoing type and "this Object current" is source object. It tries to find fields/properties of source objects with same name and type as in outgoing type. I've found in code the usage of anonymous objects as source object. The problem is this extension method available for any Object, but for primitive types and collections it is nonsence

Comment: Well, in this case I think there is no good way to prevent that at compile time. All mapping libraries I'm aware of just allow doing such call then fail at runtime (I think - I never actually called mapping api on objects you mention). Not everything can be prevented at compile time, so some kind of common sense is expected from the user of your api. Side note: instead of using `this Object` you can use `this TSource` so, another generic parameter. Then you at least can restrict that `TSource` to `class`, preventing calls on `int`, `long` and so on.

Comment: @Evk I've done it as test variant. In this case IntelliSense excludes this extension method from primitive types, but I must to set additional parameter in sharp brackets: `MyClass1 my1 = new MyClass1() { ... };` `MyClass2 my2 = my1.Foo<MyClass1, MyClass2>();` - `MyClass1` is unnecessary

Comment: And even in this case next code is working `int intVal1 = 12;` `MyClass2 intVal2 = intVal1.Foo<object, MyClass2>();` - just returns `MyClass2` object with empty properties :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You cannot. There is no generic type constraint available for such things. An option could be to specify a method which you mark `Obsolete`:

```
[Obsolete("Do not use with IEnumerable!", true)]
public static T Foo<T>(this IEnumerable current) where T : class, new()
{
    ...
}
```

You do understand the list would get endless. Another option would be a Roslyn code analyzer which checks your code for disallowed combinations, but that might be overkill.

Comment: Have an upvote for the correct answer. But marking the method as obsolete feels dirty - although i like how you think

Comment: It is dirty, but your only option. So it is either code that breaks in production, or a compiler warning. Your choice.

Comment: If go this way, it's better to use `[Obsolete("...", true)]` to produce compiler error and not just warning.

Answer (score 1):

[Patrick Hofman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/993547/patrick-hofman) allready gave the correct answer<del>, but i want to offer another possibility to deal with that problem</del>

## Possible Approach

As [Evk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311735/evk) allready stated in his comment.

Depending on how many types you want to allow, you *could explicitly allow* these types.

## Bad Approach

<del>I don't really like the Feeling of adding obsolete Tags to Enforce certain types on Genericmethods.</del>

> Warning: Do not use the following approach!

You <del>could</del> must not check for the type and throw an exception.

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="current">Dont throw in IENumerables !</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static T Foo<T>(this Object current) where T : class, new() {
        if (current is IEnumerable) {
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Type  {current.GetType()} is not supported!");
        }
        //...
}
```

**Why is this a bad approach?** -> This could result in crashing your application.

**Why is Patricks approach better?**  -> His approach results in a compiler warning/error, which is better than having an Application crash in production.

Comment: *The following only makes real sense, if you have automatic tests.* And a 100% code coverage, with all options exhausted.

Comment: To be honest, I prefer a "dirty" solution that gives me a compile time error over "cleaner" solutions that blow up in runtime.

Comment: True, the more i think about the problem - the more i come to the conclusion that your solution is way smarter.

Comment: Refactored the answer to something that is, atleast i hope so, more useful as it now states that the approach i chose is bad and why it is bad.